# What is the purpose of the .py file that is also included in the report folder of OpenERP

Tags: odoo

From the documentation, OpenERP uses rml files to display reports. These reports are generated from .sxw files. I didn't see anything about the .py files that are also included in report folders. Please what is their purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those python files in the report folders are [RML parsers](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/05_reports.html#openerp-server-pdf-output). They subclass the `report_sxw.rml_parse` class, and add extra functions to the report's local context if you need more than [the standard functions](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/05_reports.html#dynamic-content-in-openoffice-reports). If you search the `addons` project for `rml_parse` you'll find a bunch of examples.